# php create nested xml

Tags: php, xml

i have this php code to create xml.

```
  <?php 
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $document = $dom->appendChild(
      $dom->createElement('xtranslation') 
    );
    $document->textContent = '21st Century King James Version';
    
    $document->appendChild($dom->createElement('xabbreviation'))->textContent = 'KJ21';

    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    echo $dom->saveXml();
    ?>
```

but it create inline xml code like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xtranslation>21st Century King James Version<xabbreviation>KJ21</xabbreviation></xtranslation>
```

how can i get proper structure like below?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xtranslation>21st Century King James Version
  <xabbreviation>KJ21</xabbreviation>
</xtranslation>
```

It works properly if i remove

```
$document->textContent = '21st Century King James Version';
```

Comment: @Uwe sorry nope.this happen when i add content to parent tag. it works when i keep only content or child tag. but both content and child tag doesn't works

Comment: The structure of both documents you have shown is basically the same, the difference is just extra whitespace.

Comment: @CBroe yes. thanks.problem was in displaying data. when i add header("Content-type: text/xml"); it show xml data properly.

Comment: @ÄsiriLäkmäl can you add your solution as an answer and accept it later on? Nice catch with the header and maybe useful for someone who faces the same issue and the existing answers don't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in displaying data. when i add

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

it show xml data properly